# weave.inline not compatible with scipy.optimize.leastsq?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython, least-squares

I am trying to speed up a function minimization routine that uses the 'leastsq' function from scipy.optimize.  That is, I am doing the following:

```
    def errfn(pars):
        return myfn(ts,pars)-data
    pfit,success = scipy.optimize.leastsq(errfn,p0,Dfun=Dfun,col_deriv=1)
```

errfn is the function that returns the residuals; Dfun returns the Jacobian matrix; p0 is the initial parameter guess.  In pure numpy, this works.  Now, if I, for example, change myfn (or Dfun) to incorporate C code using weave.inline, the weave.inline compiler breaks.  When I call the function on its own it returns the correct value; it is only in the context of being called by the leastsq function that the compiler breaks.  Any ideas what is happening here?  Below is how I am using weave.inline:

```
def myfn(t,p):
 eta = p[0]
 theta = p[1]
 c = p[2]
 tau = p[3]
 nt = len(t)
 fs = zeros(nt)
 code = """
       double T = 10000;
       for (int i=0; i<nt; i++){
        double tprime = T*sin(pi*(t(i)-tau)/T)/pi/eta;
        fs(i) = 1-theta + 0.5*theta*(2 - tanh(c*(tprime + 0.5)) + tanh(c*(tprime - 0.5)));
       }
       """

weave.inline(code,['fs','nt','eta','theta','c','tau','t','pi'],type_converters=converters.blitz)
return fs
```

Comment: Do you get any error message when the compiler breaks? I've used leastsq with an objective function in cython and it did speed up the minimization a bit. I was thinking about trying scipy.weave too.